# Where does local const variable will get stored?

Tags: c

Where does local const variable will get stored? I have verified that, every where in function where const variable is used, get replaced with its value(like immediate value addressing mode). But if  pointer is assigned to it then it gets stored on stack. Here I do not understand one thing how processor knows its constant value. Is there any read only section in stack  like it present in .data section?

Comment: implemented defined behavior

Comment: I'm going off on a tangent, but I really think your shouldn't worry yourself with it at this stage of your learning. C is not a universal assembler. You should not think of it as one and constantly wonder what assembly it produces. C is a high level language that you use to describe *the behavior* you want your program to have. A compiler then produces code with that behavior. And if it can prove that in your program, that const variable will have a specific value, then it can constant fold. It's still the same behavior and valid program.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the processor does not know that an object is declared `const` in C.

Systems commonly have regions of memory that are marked read-only after a program is loaded, and static `const` objects are stored in such memory. For these objects, the processor enforces the read-only property.

Systems generally do not have read-only memory used for stack. This would be inherently difficult—the memory would need to be read-write when a function is starting, so that its stack frame can be constructed, but read-only at other times. So the program would be frequently changing the hardware memory protection settings. This would impair performance and is generally not considered worth while.

So programs generally have only a read-write stack available. When you declare an automatic (rather than static) `const` object, where can the compiler put it? As you note, it is often optimized into an immediate operand in instructions. However, when you take its address, it must have an address, so it must be in memory.

One idea might be that, since it is `const`, it will not chamge, so we only need one copy, so it can be stored in the static read-only section instead of on the stack. However, the C standard says that each different object has a different address. To comply with that requirement, the compiler has to create a different instance of the object in memory each time it is created in the C code. Putting it on the stack is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it totally depends on your tool-chain specific implementation. Variables are stored in RAM, program in Flash memory and constants either in RAM or Flash.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It's correct that it depends on the system. It is not correct to say that "program are stored in flash memory" in all cases. There may exist such systems but most systems uses RAM for the program.

Comment: You are correct and on microcontrollers the program is almost always stored and executed in/from the flash memory. @SupportUkraine How and from where would you get it into RAM if you only have a microcontroller?